# Checking Battery Status in Blackberry development

Tags: blackberry, java-me, system-information

I am developing an application for 8900 + 9000 Blackberry.  In my application I need to check if the battery is connected to a charger, specifically an in-car charger.

I used the following to check if the battery is charging:

```
if (DeviceInfo.getBatteryStatus() & DeviceInfo.BSTAT_CHARGING) != 0){}
```

This works fine but if the battery is fully charged then this is false.  So I tried checking `BSTAT_IS_USING_EXTERNAL_POWER and BSTAT_AC_CONTACTS` to see if either of them come as true but they are both false if battery fully charged.

I can't see any other BSTAT_ values that would work, is there a way to determine if the car is plugged in, full batter or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using &, can you use an XOR?

Comment: IPX Ares - why not post your answer as an actual answer so it can be upvoted and marked as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As IPX Ares suggested I used an XOR operator rather than &:

```
(DeviceInfo.getBatteryStatus() ^ DeviceInfo.BSTAT_CHARGING) == 0)
```